# How to implement an event-driven consumer in Apache Camel and get JMS Message

Tags: java, spring, jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

Hi I'm struggling with Apache Camel,

i want the "real" javax.jms.TextMessage in my custom Consumer-Bean. But all I get is the Message-Text as String.

Config:

```
     <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"> 
     <route id="route_dispatching"> 
        <from uri="activemq:queue:queue.dispatcher.replyqueue"/> 
        <to uri="bean:dispatcherbean"/>
       </route>
     </camelContext>
     <bean id="dispatcherbean" class="com.company.Dispatcher"/>
```

Code of Dispatcher Bean:

```
     public class Dispatcher{
           private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(Dispatcher.class);
          public void handleEvent(Object eventPayload) throws Exception
          {  
                LOG.info("got an event"); 
          }
     }
```

The eventPayload Object is of type String and not javax.jms.TextMessage. 
I tried to change uri="activemq:queue to uri="jms:queue, but then I get some Errors about missing Connection Factories :-(

Hope someone may help?

Regards, Tobi

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the type from Object to javax.jms.TextMessage in the POJO class?